# Why are my adds not showing up on android device?

Tags: admob

So after searching far more than i should have this is the best plug-in ive found so far.

'http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/free-admob-plugin-simple-prefab.167731/'

I've added the unity package to unity no problem. I then added admobplugin onto the mainCamera and the admob plugin script.

The block mock up banner shows, but actual ads are not displayed. When its built and run on the android device nothing shows up not even the mock up banner. Yes i've added my android publisher ID from admob.

QUESTION: How do i implement this fully?

If anyone has tried and done this before i'd like to hear how you got it working.

Answer (score 0):

You will have the folder Editor and in that you will have admob folder and the scripts.

You will need to create an empty game object and add the script to that object. If your using admob you will be provided with a key. Use that key in the code.

The code in javascript :

function Start () 
{
        AdMobAndroid.init( "yourkey" );
        AdMobAndroid.createBanner( AdMobAndroidAd.phone320x50,AdMobAdPlacement.BottomLeft);
}

Let me know if you need any assistance. I hope this helps.

Comment: Add what script to the empty game object? and im just getting errors, 'unkown identifier admobandroid' & 'admobadplacement'